# Approximating measurable function by continuous ones

Tags: measure-theory

Say that I have a measure space $(X,\mu)$ and a measurable function $f$ which is non-negative and bounded from above. $\mu(X)<\infty$. Now, the approximation under my concern is in almost everywhere convergence sense.

It suffice to consider the case when $f$ is a characteristic function of a set, say $A$. A standrad argument would be to require $\mu$ to be a regular measure, thus allowing to approximate $A$ by open and compact sets and then build a smooth function by Urysohn's Lemma.

But for the case I am considering now, I can't show that $\mu$ is a regular measure. What other approximation method can I consider if $\mu$ is indeed not regualr?

P.S.: If $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to a regular measure, is it regular? And what If $\mu$ is singular to this regular measure?

Comment: I don't think that this belongs on meta, but rather on the main part of the site.

Comment: Consider having a look at the very end of the first chapter of Lieb & Loss *Analysis*. (I assume that $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ or some metric locally compact space).

Comment: What is $X$? And its topology?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Let's say $X$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual topology. And sorry that I made a mistake in my original problem. I should ask for almost everywhere convergence.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I did check on that one. But isn't regularity of the measure needed there?

Comment: You seem to be just wanting Egorov's theorem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov's_theorem

Answer (score 3):

You can consider the method outlined in Lieb-Loss's *Analysis*, 2nd ed., Corollary 1.19. You will need your measure to be Borel, of course. But you cannot escape that, if you want continuous functions to be measurable.